# When should one check in to get the best of optionally allocated seats?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, tips-and-tricks, seating, easyjet

Easyjet recently launched an allocated seat system.

Basically the rules are:

- If you pay you can choose your seat. The front seats and the emergency exit seats are more expensive.
- If you don't, your seats are allocated in a random way when you check in.

Say one does not want to pay to pick his seat, but still wants to get a good one (at the front of the plane to be first to get out), when should he check in?

I would assume that if you check in early, then you get the bad seats, because Easyjet is hoping they can sell the good (and expensive) seats later. So maybe checking in as late as possible is a good idea, since by that time they will have to give you whatever is available, and they'll probably only have good seats left.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't easily determine your chances without any experience with EasyJet flights.
Try to find out whether there's any chance to get a good place right here and right now just by negotiating with the check-in personnel. This is quite a personal thing.

On the other hand, I think the best time is the middle of the check-in. During that time you'll have more information about good place availability, and, after a few flights you'll find out the right moment to start.

Classical trial-and-error thing.
Good luck with that :)